# Sql server full text indexing wild card search

Tags: .net, asp.net, full-text-search

I am having a trouble using full text indexing in sql server

Is it possible to search columns which starts with a specific word using full text indexing ??

Comment: Please read your question yourself. After that, please fix it. The first paragraph of your question doesn't contain any punctuation, which makes it very hard to read.

Comment: it was my first post and posted in a hurry :-)
now i have edited my post now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't anchor your searches like this with full text searches.  The best you could do would be to use a `LIKE` (which is *awful* advice) if you want to find specific values at the front of a column like this.

Comment: the table have above 20M  so that we are now optimizing the query for better performance currently we are using like in all our sps .While changing to FTS the performance is increased but some functionality like what in question have disappeared..:-(